# Что делать, если внутри класса не видны компоненты Swing?

Tags: java

Есть класс, который на панель добавляет Button и TextField. Но, когда в ColorAction пытаюсь прописать действия при нажатии на кнопку, компилятор не видит panel, Button, Textfield. В чём ошибка?

```
class BPanel extends JPanel
{
    public BPanel()
    {

        JButton Button = new JButton("Button_");
        JTextField Text = new JTextField(15);

        add(Button);
        add(Text);

        ActionListener actionListener = new ColorAction();
        Button.addActionListener(actionListener);       
    }

    protected class ColorAction implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {           
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel, "ppppp"); //ошибка, не видит panel
        }
    }

}

class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
    public ButtonFrame()
    {
        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(500, 200);

        BPanel panel = new BPanel();
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(panel) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Гм, я тоже не вижу такое поле/переменную. Откуда вы взяли `panel` вообще?

Comment: @falstaf, я добавил класс, в котором создается panel

Comment: @roman_ya111 а с чего вы взяли, что локальная переменная из конструктора совершенно другого класса (**ButtonFrame**) должна быть видна в другом классе (**BPanel**)?  Почитайте поподробнее об областях видимости переменных

Comment: @DreamChild , а к Button и Text я по этой же причине не могу обращаться?

Comment: Button и Tex - это локальные переменные конструктора  класса **BPanel**. И, разумеется, к этим переменным в можете обращаться только из этого конструктора. То есть не сможете их использовать даже в других методах этого класса. Ещё раз настоятельно рекомендую вам почитать про области видимости переменных, это даст ответ на все аналогичные вопросы